# imagePickerController don't go delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to choose video from `PhotosAlbum`, follows this code, NOW I can choose video but can not go delegate method:

```
imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
```

I don't know why, any help is appreciated.

```
UIImagePickerController*m_pPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            [m_pPickerController setEditing:NO];
            m_pPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
            m_pPickerController.delegate = self;
            m_pPickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
            m_pPickerController.delegate = self;
            m_pPickerController.videoQuality=UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
            [self presentViewController:m_pPickerController animated:YES completion:^{
                m_pPickerController.delegate = self;
            }];
```

Comment: Are you getting any warning on the line were you are assigning the delegate to self?

Comment: Is your ViewController, where you are presenting this image picker, implementing the delegate protocol?

Comment: I don't have any warning about this. implementing the delegate protocol when I click cancel.